Slim select doesn't work when in a wire-elements/modal LIVEWIRE V3
When implementing slim select inside a livewire modal (wire-elements/modal), the search doesn't work, I'm using alpine.js to initialize the component, it loads everything correctly, it doesn't lose the css anymore, but the search inside the modal doesn't work, only outside the modal in other components livewire works fine
<div x-data="" class="w-full flex flex-col gap-2 pl-6 pb-8" wire:ignore>
    
    <x-label for="selectuser" class="">Ordem Serviço:</x-label>
    
    <select id="selectElement" class="" 
            wire:model.live="selectedOS" x-init="let slim = new SlimSelect({
                            select: '#selectElement',
                        })
                        console.log(slim);"
    >
        
        <option value="" selected>Selecione a OS</option>
        
        @foreach ($OSs as $OS)
            <option value="{{ $OS->id }}">{{ $OS->nome }}</option>
        @endforeach
        
    </select>
    
</div>



Ordem Serviço:

Selecione a OS
                    </select>
                </div>


Hi please visit this link here for a possible solution.
